# How to search a text file and print that line in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user to enter a text file name and once opened asks the user to enter a stars name that it will look in the file for and print the information on that line. 
It's probably obvious to most of you but whenever I open the file and enter the star name is prints out the whole text file. Would someone be able to tell me where I'm going wrong and why it isn't just printing the line instead of the whole file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream input;
string fileName, starName, Name, ProperName, HRnumber, HDnumber, distance;

cout << "Enter the file name >> ";
cin >> fileName;
input.open(fileName.c_str());

if(input.is_open())
{
    cout << "Enter star proper name >> " ;
    cin >> starName;

    while(getline(input, starName, '~'))
    {
          cout << starName << ' ' << Name << ' ' << ProperName << ' ' << HRnumber<< ' '  << HDnumber<< ' '  << distance;
    }

}
else
{
    cout << "The file \"" << fileName << "\" does not exist.";
}
input.close();
}
```

Comment: getline does not work like you think it does(in the while you are overwriting starName and not comparing to it).

Answer (score 0):

First, function `std::getline(input,targetstr,delim)` reads in a complete line from `input` into string `targetstr`, whereas `delim` tells the function which character to treat as the line ending. As you are passing character `'~'`, and I suppose your file does not contain any `~`, then the first `getline`-call will read in the complete file into variable `starName`. As you print `starName`, you consequently print the complete file contents.

Once having fixed this, note that you do not parse the line read in, you don't check it you are at the line of interest, and you print empty strings when accessing variables `Name`,... and so forth. There is no magic which maps line contents to your variables as intended, and there is also no magic that checks if you are at the line of interest.

So start with the following as starting point; come back to SO one you are stuck again:

```
std::string line;
while(getline(input, line))  // use default line endings, i.e. '\n'
{
      // check if line starts with starName (your job to try):
      if (...) {
          // parse the contents of the line (you job to try): 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the `getline` could be by the use of `~` which is not present in your file. 
Refer to this example:

```
 std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
  std::getline (std::cin,name);
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
```

In your case `starName` is printing the whole content of the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Hassan, I've used the ~ in get line because the different fields are seperated by ~. Could my problem be because I have a space in between certain star names?